# In the same column in excel, how do I exclude every cell that starts with a specific letter,

Tags: excel

I cant do it with more than one letter at the time.
The filters that come with excel do not give that option 
ex. exclude all words starting with A D and Z in the same column

Comment: Use an [advanced filter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-4c9222fe-8529-4cd7-a898-3f16abdff32b).

Answer (score 0):

With data in column **A**, in **B2** enter:

```
=IF(OR(LEFT(A2,1)="A", LEFT(A2,1)="D", LEFT(A2,1)="Z"),1,0)
```

and filter out any ones in column **B**:

[image]